# Chart.js How can I embed additional values to each data point in radar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

With the line chart, I am able to embed additional data and have it show up in the tooltip. However, if I try to do the same with the radar chart no values are shown. How do I add essential information to each data-point on the radar chart and have it show up in the tooltip?

Below I have a working line chart with additional values for each data-point, displayed with the tooltip. Additionally I have the same chart duplicated with `type: 'radar'`

```js
var data = [{
        //x: 'Item 1',
        y: 2,
        id: 'test-10'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 2',
        y: 4,
        id: 'test-20'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 3',
        y: 5,
        id: 'test-30'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 4',
        y: 6,
        id: 'test-40'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 5',
        y: 8,
        id: 'test-50'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 6',
        y: 12,
        id: 'test-60'
    }];
    var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                data: data,
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                        var multistringText = ['Value: ' + tooltipItems.yLabel];
                        multistringText.push('ID: ' + data['datasets'][tooltipItems.datasetIndex]['data'][tooltipItems.index].id);
                        return multistringText;
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
    var ctx = document.getElementById('radarChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                data: data,
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                        var multistringText = ['Value: ' + tooltipItems.yLabel];
                        multistringText.push('ID: ' + data['datasets'][tooltipItems.datasetIndex]['data'][tooltipItems.index].id);
                        return multistringText;
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 400px; display: inline-block">
  <canvas id="lineChart" width="100" height="70"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="width: 300px; display: inline-block">
  <canvas id="radarChart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var data = [{
        //x: 'Item 1',
        y: 2,
        id: 'test-10'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 2',
        y: 4,
        id: 'test-20'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 3',
        y: 5,
        id: 'test-30'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 4',
        y: 6,
        id: 'test-40'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 5',
        y: 8,
        id: 'test-50'
    },
    {
        //x: 'Item 6',
        y: 12,
        id: 'test-60'
    }];
    var ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                data: data,
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                        var multistringText = ['Value: ' + tooltipItems.yLabel];
                        multistringText.push('ID: ' + data['datasets'][tooltipItems.datasetIndex]['data'][tooltipItems.index].id);
                        return multistringText;
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
    var ctx = document.getElementById('radarChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'radar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                data: data.map(item => item.y),
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
            }]
        },
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function (tooltipItems) {
                        return 'Value: ' + data[tooltipItems.index].y + ', ID: ' + data[tooltipItems.index].id;
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 400px; display: inline-block">
  <canvas id="lineChart" width="100" height="70"></canvas>
</div>
<div style="width: 300px; display: inline-block">
  <canvas id="radarChart" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
</div>
```

I think the key point is to be aware of how each chart type wants the data to be structured. In the above, a `map()` function is used to present the `y` values as an array for the radar chart. Then, to get the correct tooltip information, the tooltip index is used to retreive that element's values from the full `data` array. The [label callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) seems to return a string rather than an array.